# Enable Orientation on specific page on MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

At the moment, for various reasons, the Landscape orientation is disabled on my Android MAUI application globally :

In MainActiviy.cs,

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity 
{ 
    //... 
}
```

However, on one **specific** View in my application, I would like to be able to rotate my device and have a different layout on Landscape orientation. Is there a way to re-enable the auto-orientation on a specific page, or at least to disable manually the auto-orientation page by page except that one, instead of going with MainActivity for the whole application ? For the moment I'm focusing on Android only, multiplatform might come later but this is not a priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after looking arround, I actually ended up finding the solution, with platform-specific code, by overriding the page's `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` methods :

```cs
object SOToRestore {  get; set; }

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

#if ANDROID
SOToRestore = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation;
Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
#endif
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

#if ANDROID
    if (SOToRestore is Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation SO) Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
#endif
}
```

I don't know if there's an easier way to achieve this in MAUI, but this one is actually way simpler than messing arround in MainActivity. If anyone ends up with a similar problem, the different options for `ScreenOrientation` can be found here in [.Net documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.pm.screenorientation?view=net-android-34.0) and detailed in [Android Developper documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#screenOrientation).

Comment: I think you made some copy-paste mistakes there, it should be `base.OnAppearing();` and `Portrait` in the second part. Note that  instead of using `Portrait` you may want to read the previous value in your `OnAppearing()` method and store it in a member variable to then restore the original value in `OnDisappearing()`, because there are more values/possibilities than just `Landscape` and `Portrait`.

Comment: Oops indeed, I'm fixing this right away. And regarding the original value, thanks for the suggestion, as my app is locked on portrait mode I didn't bother making my solution that general but I'll add it to the answer.