# MainDisplayInfoChanged call inconsistency in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

This question is the continuation of [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78123738/enable-orientation-on-specific-page-on-maui/78124285#78124285). To give a brief summary,

> On one specific View in my application, I would like to be able to rotate my device and have a different layout on Landscape orientation. Is there a way to re-enable the auto-orientation on a specific page

I'm handling the rotation on my view with this piece of code

```cs
object SOToRestore {  get; set; }

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

#if ANDROID
SOToRestore = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation;
Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
#endif
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

#if ANDROID
    if (SOToRestore is Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation SO) Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
#endif
}
```

I want to be able to react to the MainDisplayInfoChanged, to change the Content of my view when the orientation changes, and it works except on one specific case : on the loading of the view.

When I have my phone/emulator turned on the side on the previous view (but still on portrait mode), and I open my view, the previous piece of code works and my view rotates as I want, but without calling the MainDisplayInfoChanged event.

A thing to note : this bug doesn't happen on the very first loading of the view in the app lifetime. It only happens after I go back to previous page and open it again.

I can however confirm MainDisplayInfo actually changed, if I print its value in the OnAppearing event it returns "Portrait", and if I add a way to print it with a button manually after page has finished loading, it returns "Landscape", but without calling the event at any point between these two calls.

I provided a [minimal reproductible example](https://github.com/gchapeaux/MRE_ScreenRotation), with a label automatically updated every time OnMainDisplayInfoChanged is called. At any point, a button can be clicked to display the current value of DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation. The steps to reproduce my issue :

- Launch the app and orient the phone / emulator on landscape mode. *At this point the app should be sideway.*
- Click on the button to open the responsive view. *The screen app orients correctly, and the Label should read Landscape mode.*
- Click on the Back button. *Clicking on the query button should confirm : on this view, Orientation value is Portrait.*
- Click on the button to open the responsive view again. *Now comes the bug : the Label reads Portrait, despite the Orientation value being now Landscape. And at no moment MainDisplayInfoChanged got called.*

**EDIT**
I tried setting the RequestedOrientation on my previous view, so its value is set before we perform navigation to the new page. Sadly it didn 't solve the issue. It seems the value of MainDisplayInfo.Orientation is set by force without it raising the event.

Comment: Do you mean that when the screen is rotated,  “MAIN DISPLAY INFO CHANGED” does not appear in the console and the text does not change?

Comment: I tried running the example you provided, and RespModeLabel did display an error as portrait when entering ResponsivePage for the second time, but the MainDisplayInfoChanged event could always be triggered normally (console output was normal and counter count was correct), so the problem was only that RespModeLabel displayed an error.

Comment: @sean-he-msft I mean when I change RequestedOrientation from Portrait to Landscape when the change occurs, if the phone is already on the side the event isn't called. I edited my minimal reproductible example to add a button to show this : start the app, set your device/enulator horizontally, and press the button to switch RequestedOrientation, you should see MainDisplayInfoChanged isn't called, but if you querry its value manually with the first button it actually changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your problem. Since the MaindisplayInfochanged is a global event, when the OnDisappearing method is setting the screen to the portrait, the `Maindisplayinfochanged` should also be triggered, but it does not. This statement can be verified by setting the code in MainActivity file:

```
public class MainActivity: MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.Orientation == Orientation.Landscape){}
        else if(newConfig.Orientation == Orientation.Portrait){}
    }
}
```

After setting the above code and Breakpoint on it, you will find that you jump to this method after running the OnDisappearing method, but `MaindisplayInfochanged` doesn't be triggered. So it's recommand to [post this issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) .

As the workaround, you can set the RespModeLable's Text as the Global variable，then call it in the MianActivity's method:

```
public partical class ResponsivePage:ContentPage
{
    public static Lable lable1;
    public ResonsivePage()
    {
        //...
        lable1 = RespModeLabel;
        //...
    }
}

public class MainActivity: MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.Orientation == Orientation.Landscape)
        {
            ResponsivePage.lable1.Text = "I'm in Landscape Mode";
        }
        else if(newConfig.Orientation == Orientation.Portrait)
        {
            ResponsivePage.lable1.Text = "I'm in Portrait Mode";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I needed, working from the OnConfigurationChanged method worked perfectly. As my actual situation is less trivial than just setting a Label text, I went on using [Messengers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-8.0) and it now works exactly like I want !

Comment: A little comment regarding the issue tho, I have it on emulaotr, but when testing on my real device I can't reproduce it. It might be related to Android version.